# Extract first word of a string (untilSpace)

Tags: java, string, split

The question is:

> Write a function `untilSpace(s)` that returns a substring of `s` **starting at the beginning** and **extending until a space** is found. The space is not included in the returned value. The argument will always have a space.

> Examples:
>
> ```
> untilSpace("ab cde") -> "ab"
> ```

My code solution is:

```
public String untilSpace(String s){
    String str = s;
    str = str.replaceFirst(" ", "");
    System.out.println(str);
    return str;  
}
```

I managed to remove the space, but I still need to find a way to remove the rest of the string that comes after the space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: This is not a dupe of using split. Using split is *one* way of doing it, but not the required way or even necessarily a "better" way.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex replace:

```
public String untilSpace(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll(" .*", "");
}
```

This works by replacing everything matched by the regex expression with nothing - effectively deleting it.

The regex `" .*"` means "a space followed by any chars to the end of input".

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken he essentially wants str.split(" ")[0]

Comment: I think this is a fairly unusual way to solve it. Given that there is `split` (also with match-limiting) and `indexOf` + `substring`. But sure, works, upvoted.

Comment: @Zabuzard actually replaceAll is a far more general way to extract near-arbitrary parts of a String. Using split assumes the start and end of the target are splittable there, plus split does much more work.

Comment: @MatthewKerian in this case, yes. But in the general case, split is not as versatile as replaceAll - see previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

### [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int))

You can split the string on space and use the first element:

```
String firstWord = text.split(" ")[0];
```

You can also improve this approach by limiting the amount of elements you are interested in (in case there are lots of spaces):

```
String firstWord = text.split(" ", 2)[0];
```

---

### [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) + [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))

A more manual approach involving `indexOf` and `substring` also works well:

```
int index = text.indexOf(' ');
String firstWord = text.substring(0, index);
```

Note that this approach will crash if there is no space contained in `text`, due to `indexOf` returning `-1` which is an invalid index for `substring`. But in your case it is fine since your task says

> The argument will always have a space.